Integrating C DLL into UWP platform with DLLImport
I'm attempting to integrate a Chainway R3 barcode scanner device into a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) project. The device manufacturer provided a C-coded DLL, but I'm struggling to successfully run its functions into my UWP project. Prior to working on the UWP platform, I tested the DLL in a C# console project and encountered no issues, which gave me confidence in my ability to adapt it to the UWP project. However, my efforts have been met with partial success, as the DLL's OpenUSB function returns an error code of 6, which corresponds to "ERR_OPEN_USB_FAILURE" according to the documentation.
Documentation can be found here UHFAPI.dll Documentation
Here's my codes
package.appxmanifest capabilities
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="humanInterfaceDevice"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="hidTelephony"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb"/>
</Capabilities>

mainpage.xaml.cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    uhf = UHFAPI.getInstance();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (uhf != null)
    {
        uhf.OpenUsb();
    }
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (uhf != null)
    {
        var version = uhf.GetHardwareVersion();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(version);
    }
}

uhfapi.cs code in this github gist
dll can be found here with the .lib files and headers



It looks to me like something else is using the device. That's why it cannot access it. I don't think this error is related to UWP. It's a lower level layer.

Hi @JuanR, I can confirm that it's not. I did a full complete shutdown, restart the machine and did the test straight with the UWP app and same error.

Please post the full exception stack.
